# pthread_create(), how do I get the returned value from the passed function

Tags: c++, unix, pthreads, posix

How do I get the returned void pointer of the function that I pass the pthread_create?

```
static void* pthread_sendRequest(void* name){
    RequestChannel chan(*(string*) name, RequestChannel::CLIENT_SIDE);
    string returnValue = chan.send_request("Hi");
    return (void*) &returnValue;

}

pthread_create(thread, NULL, pthread_sendRequest, new string(&"worker #" [i]));
```

How do I get the return value, of pthread_sendRequest when it is passed to pthread_ create, so I can cast it back to a string pointer and get the actual string?

Does the void** in pthread_join(thread, void**) grab it for me?

Comment: There's not really something like a `returned value` from a thread function. If you need to exchange data between threads, use the parameters of the thread function.

Comment: *If the start_routine returns, the effect is as if there was an implicit call to pthread_exit() using the return value of start_routine as the exit status.* - http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/pthread_create.html. Also, as this is C++, `std::thread t{func, std::ref(returnedData)};` and make `func` return `void` and take  whatever data to return by reference.

Comment: @chris IIRC trying to _return_ any _real_ values using this mechanism (e.g. allocated strings or such), besides constant error indicator references, didn't work well. I'm not really sure, but I stay off using this feature (I think it's mostly because `void*` is too vague).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, It can have problems if the reference becomes dangling in the time the thread takes, so you have to be careful there, as always when using references. I haven't heard of any other problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As other answers have indicates, the value returned from the thread function can be captured by passing in a pointer to a buffer to obtain that returned value.

However, in your example, your thread function is returning a pointer to a non-static local variable, which is invalid (whether the function is executed in a thread or not) because once the function exits the local object no longer exists.

You could maybe do something like:

```
static void* pthread_sendRequest(void* name){
    RequestChannel chan(*(string*) name, RequestChannel::CLIENT_SIDE);
    string* returnValue = new string(chan.send_request("Hi"));
    return (void*) returnValue;

}

pthread_create(thread, NULL, pthread_sendRequest, new string(&"worker #" [i]));

// ...

void* temp = NULL;
pthread_join(*thread, &temp); 

string* returnValue = (string*) temp;

// when done with returnValue
delete returnValue;
```

Answer (score 1):

When you call [pthread_join](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_join.3.html) it takes a pointer to a `void*` into which that return value is copied.  (The example linked from that page illustrates usage, but it's pretty obvious anyway).

Comment: Your newly posted code evidences a completely different problem - I'm not going to bother covering it as Michael Burr's already been kind enough to do so.  Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

If `func` is returned, or calls `pthread_exit`, you can get the exit status in `pthread_join`

```
int pthread_join(pthread_t tid, void **thread_return);
```

`tid` is the identifier that `pthread_create` fills in.

Comment: does thread_return is literally the same pointer that is returned if you call the func function alone?

Comment: @NoorThabit I'm not following your question, that argument is filled by the caller of `pthread_join`, and will be filled with the exit status if the thread exits.

Comment: @NoorThabit: if `func` calls `pthread_exit(my_thread_ptr)` (explicitly or implicitly by coding `return my_void_ptr;`), then that *is* the value that will be copied into `*thread_return`.  (On systems that support thread cancellation, when joining a cancelled thread a sentinel such as `PTHREAD_CANCELED` may be copied into `*thread_return`).

Comment: @TonyD I updated the question. I'm sorry I wasn't very clear.

Comment: @YuHao Have a look at the question again, I updated it. Thanks a lot!